# Magento can't categorize products

Tags: magento, categories

I have a store that has over 4000 products. I have about 2000 that still need to be placed into categories. I've been doing this by going to "Catalog > Manage Categories" and then going to category products and clicking on the products that should be assigned to the category. After clicking "save category" I noticed that the numbers weren't updating and that products weren't being updated. What would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have flat categories enabled? If so you will need to run the reindex process for your changes to show up.

Comment: I'm not sure I will check. What exactly is "flat categories"

Comment: What are the differences between: Use Flat Catalog Product vs Use Flat Catalog Category?

Comment: I just enabled both of these options and re-indexed and I'm still having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the value of `max_input_vars` in `php.ini` file or in `.htaccess`.`max_input_vars`, which is 1000 by default that why you can not save more than 1000 product in same category. Use below code in .htaccess file and fix the bug.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value max_input_vars 10000
</IfModule>
```